# Tableau Legend Highlighting

Tags: tableau-api

I have created Tableau worksheet and color coded my chart by Department name and added legend to my workbook. Usually Tableau allows legend highlighting - you can select an item in the legend and all related items in workbook are highlighted. For some reason "Highlight Selected Items" option is disabled for the legend in my workbook.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this out with sample data and couldn't repro the issue, so could you provide a copy of your workbook for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out the answer myself. On Dashboard pane toolbar there is option (one on the left to presentation mode icon) to enable/disable workbook highlighting. For some reason it was disabled. I have re-enabled it and I'm able to use legend highlighting now.